# Can't store data in HDF5 with Panda?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

I am trying to store large dataframe in HDF5 format but I always having errors. I should not use the good way to do it but I don't see where I am wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nrows=5
ncols=5

colnames=[]
for i in range(0,ncols):
    colnames.append('C'+str(i))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(9,size=(nrows,ncols)),columns=colnames)
```

Which builds a simple dataframe:

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
   C0  C1  C2  C3  C4
0   1   4   5   5   3
1   8   2   7   1   4
2   2   7   6   4   2
3   8   2   4   3   3
4   8   6   5   3   6
```

---

Now when I try:

```
df.to_hdf('test1.hdf','test',mode='w')
```

or:

```
df.to_hdf('test_table.hdf','test',format='table',mode='w')
```

I obtain:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_f_close'
```

---

I try also this method:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('data/store.h5', 'w')
store['df'] = df
```

But I get:

```
AssertionError: stale weak reference to dead node ``/df/axis0``
```

---

What is the proper way to do this?
Thank you.

I am using:
Python 3.4.1
pandas 0.15.2
tables 3.0.0

Comment: This code works for me using the same conditions except tables = 3.1.1. Maybe upgrade tables??

Comment: Yes indeed, it now work with the upgrade. Is there a best way to write hdf file between the two methods I presented?

Comment: I don't know if one method is superior or more panda-ific. I generally use the ``.to_hdf()`` method if for no other reason than it's easier to read. I already have my dataframe; one method call and it's written to an HDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by James in comments, it was just a bug fixed when updating to the last version of *Tables*.